Bayesian nn-with DenseFlipout layer, I cannot use the functional API
For customizing my neural network, I wanna use the functional API. But DenseFlipoutlayer doesn't work with the typical input layer tf.keras.Input(unit number). The error message says that it is not a tensor but a tuple, so it does not have 'rank' and it cannot enter to the DenseFilpout layer. But how can I make the neural network without the input layer? I don't know how to solve it.. Thanks for helping me. It means a lot to me!!
Here are the sinppet, the output and the error message.
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_dim,))
print(f'Input tensor: {inputs}')
x = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(16, activation='relu')(inputs)
print(f'After first DenseFlipout: {x}')
x = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(8, activation='relu')(x)
print(f'After second DenseFlipout: {x}')
outputs = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
print(f'Output tensor: {outputs}')

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)


Output

Input tensor: <KerasTensor shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32, sparse=None, name=keras_tensor>
-

Error

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'`

I wanna know how to use the functional API with DenseFilpout layers.
